# My binary subtraction program seems to not work for one specific value

Tags: python, binary, subtraction

So I'm making this subtraction program and really don't know why it does not work for these two values. For every other one it works though?

```py
def binmin(x, y):
    lenx = len(x)
    leny = len(y)
    x1 = list(x)
    y1 = list(y)
    difference= 0
    one = 0
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(x)):
        difference = str((int(x1[lenx - 1 - i])) - int(y1[leny - 1 - i]))
        if difference == "-1":
            difference = 2 - int(y1[leny - 1 - i])
            one = 1
        
        elif difference == "-2":
            one = 1
            difference = 0

        else:
            one = 0

        y1[leny - i - 2] = int(y1[leny - i - 2]) + one

        result = str(difference) + str(result)

    return result

print(binmin("11110000","00010001"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
if difference == "-1":
    difference = 2 - int(y1[leny - 1 - i])
    one = 1
```

to:

```
if difference == "-1":
    difference = 1
    one = 1
```

When `difference` is initially `"-1"`, you need to borrow, so you're effectively adding `2` to the difference.  Since the difference was originally `-1`, you want `2-1` = `1` for the new difference.

The original adjustment only worked if `int(y1[leny - 1 - i])` was `1`, which it might not be if it had previously been adjusted by an earlier borrow, in which case it could be `2`.